# Reverse for 'api' not found. 'api' is not a valid view function or pattern name with rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a few api with django-rest-framework, my routing is like this below.

set `/api/genres` under `/api`

```
from rest_framework import routers
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import include

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'genres', GenreViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/',include(router.urls), name='api'),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
```

Now I want to use this url in template, so I tried two patterns, but both shows error.

How should I make the link for api??

```
<a href="{% url 'api' %}">api</a>
Reverse for 'api' not found. 'api' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

<a href="{% url 'genres' %}">genre</a>
Reverse for 'genres' not found. 'genres' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Router provides argument [`basename`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage) which is using to reverse url.

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'genres', GenreViewSet, basename='genres')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/',include(router.urls)),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
```

Note that DRF's viewset has multiple urls. So you need to specify which one you want to use by adding specific suffix `-list` or `-detail`. First one will give you url of viewset `list()` and `create()` actions. And second using for `retrieve()` and `update()`.

So in template it would be something like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'genres-list' %}">api</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is a great advice how to use `basename`